# Form Manipulate PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

in php i am displaying a table on click of a button after entering a ref number.

like, if i enter a ref number and click the button it will fetch the corresponding details like name , d.o.b , and other fields along with the current status corresponds to that ref number . ( the way i allow the admin to store the data was excel import )

This works fine now .

On a second thought i had in mind that, what if i allow the admin himself to choose the fields he need as some may need name , d.o.b and status alone and some may need name , age , d.ob and other fields . (however the data import is same excel)

In that case what i want was the admin to manipulate the fields himself which will reflect in db also.

i tried figuring how to start . googled too, but failed getting an idea on how to proceed.

what i ask now was not the code to proceed. if you can help me with an idea on how to do it, i will proceed and ask further helps if needed.

Comment: Hii, accordng to my understanding You would need 3 tables, one for storing the fields (Ex: name, d.o.b, .. etc) second would be having user and the field chosen by the user in terms of their respective ids, and the third would store the actual data for their fields with the same field selts provided in first table. When the admin selects the user just take the fields from the relation table

Comment: @sam Thanks for the lead mate , Let me try that and get back to you with what i get